# Hyperref not working says to install a package

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink

Iam using Texstudio and is new to Latex.
To include a link in my pdf, i typed

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}
\end{document}
```

But it asks to install some package.

[image: screenshot]

But when I click install, nothing happens...

I also tried \href instead of \url. But same result.

Comment: perhaps something blocks the on-the-fly installation. Go to the miktex console and try to install the missing packages manually.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But i can't open it.When i try to open MikTex console, it says "Miktex console is already running"

Comment: Then close at first everything and them try again.

Comment: The issue has been solved. Thanks everyone

Comment: When i typed \usepackage{hyperref}  and clicked 'compile' -as i said in the question- a package installation window appeared. When i clicked install, I thought nothing happened. when i clicked again, i thought it is the same installation window that has appeared.  But it was after asking the question that i noticed that after each time i click install , a different package is installed...after about 10-20 clicks , all packages were installed, so it worked after that!!!